# Why duality pairing $\langle w,v \rangle=\int_{[0,T]}\langle w(t), v(t)\rangle_{V^*\times V}dt$ can be defined this way?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Consider evolution triple $(V,H,V^*)$ ($H$ is a pivot space). I introduce new spaces

$\mathcal{V}=L^2([0,T], V)$ (a space of measurable functions $v:[0,T]\to V$, $\int_{[0,T]}\|v(t)\|_V^2dt<\infty$),

$\mathcal{V}^*=L^2([0,T],V^*)$

$\mathcal{W}=\{w\in \mathcal{V}\,|\,w^{'}\in\mathcal{V}^* \}$ is endowed with graph norm, i.e., $\|w\|_{\mathcal{W}}=\|w\|_{\mathcal{V}}+\|w^{'}\|_{\mathcal{V^{*}}}$, (separable and reflexive Banach space)

$\mathcal{H}=L^2([0,T], H)$.

Then we obtain continuous embeddings $$\mathcal{W}\subset \mathcal{V}\subset\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{H}^*\subset \mathcal{V}^*.$$
The duality pairing between $\mathcal{V}^*$ and $\mathcal{V}$ is denoted by
$$\langle w,v \rangle_{\mathcal{V}^*\times\mathcal{V}}=\int_{[0,T]}\langle w(t), v(t)\rangle_{V^*\times V}dt\qquad (1)$$
for $w\in \mathcal{V}^*$ and $v\in \mathcal{V}$. My question is: Can we denoted this way? - I mean we define it in very particular way $(1)$ - why can we define it this way? Yet $\langle w,v \rangle_{\mathcal{V}^*\times\mathcal{V}}=w(v)$. So, what allows us to define $(1)$ and what stays behined uniqueness of $(1)$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Riesz Representation Theorem?  Your example seems to be an application thereof.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz–Markov–Kakutani_representation_theorem

Comment: I am not sure if it is so obvious.

Comment: Ugh... the link got mangled:  http://goo.gl/4JUigw  And no, I am not sure that it is *obvious*, but it has that flavour.

Comment: I don't think Riesz - Markov - Kakutani theorem is the best idea in here. Instead we can use duality relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [A question about duality relation $L_p([0,T];V)^*=L_q([0,T];V^*)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2389510/a-question-about-duality-relation-l-p0-tv-l-q0-tv). Naturally, one can also prove the opposite, i.e.,

*To each $f\in X^*$ there corresponds exactly one $v\in L_q([0,T];V^*)$ with $$\langle f,u \rangle=\int_{0}^{T}\langle v(t), u(t)\rangle_{V^*\times V}dt$$
for all $u\in X$.*