# A question about duality relation $L_p([0,T];V)^*=L_q([0,T];V^*)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $V$ be a reflexive and separable Banach space and let $1<p<\infty$, $p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1.$ We set $X=L_p([0,T];V)$. Then the following holds:

To each function $v\in L_q([0,T];V^*)$ there corresponds a unique functional $f\in X^*$ with $$\langle f,u \rangle=\int_{0}^{T}\langle v(t), u(t)\rangle_{V^*\times V}dt$$
for all $u\in X$.

Proof. Fix a function $v\in L_q([0,T];V^*)$. Let $f\colon L_p([0,T];V)\to \mathbb{R}$ and define it as follows $$f(u)=\int_{0}^{T}\langle v(t), u(t)\rangle_{V^*\times V}dt.$$
Naturally, $f$ is linear. From the Holder inequality $$\int_{0}^{T}|\langle v(t), u(t)\rangle_{V^*\times V}|dt\le (\int_{0}^{T}\|v(t)\|^q_{V^*}dt)^{1/q}\cdot(\int_{0}^{T}\|u(t)\|^p_{V}dt)^{1/p}$$
I easily obtain that $f\in X^*$. What about the uniqueness of $f$? May it follow from the above considerations?

Comment: What do you mean by 'uniqueness'? You just defined $f$ in this way, i.e., it is unique.

Comment: I was wondering if the way I defined it, is the only one - unique. What if I can define it in another way? Then every $v$ may be indentyfied with more than one functional from $X^*$.

Comment: You have defined one map from $L^q(V^*)$ to $L^p(V)^*$. There are, of course, many more: $v \mapsto \big( u \mapsto 2 \, \int \langle u,v \rangle \mathrm dt\big)$. But typically, you fix one such map and show that it is a continuous bijection in order to get a characterization of the dual space.

Comment: I also thought about continuous bijection. Anyway, it is nice to get confirmation by someone smarter. Thanks for comments.